# GroupBy and filter with aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have an order schema which like below object represent it :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59dce1fa2d57920d3e62bdf3"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-10T15:06:34.205+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-10T15:06:34.128+0000"), 
    "_customer" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd44"), 
    "_distributor" : ObjectId("59dce1f92d57920d3e62bd39"), 
    "status" : "NEW", 
}
```

now i want to group  and filter it.
group by same `_customer` and filter with `createdAt` field. how to use Aggregation to handle both?

Comment: Your question is broad. But follow the aggregation documentation using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) then possibly [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below using `$match`, `$group` and `$project`

```
Orders.aggregate([
   {$match  : { createdAt : "<your createdAt value here>"}},
   {$group : {
       _id : { _id : "$_customer" },
       data : { $addToSet : { _id : "$_id" , updatedAt : "$updatedAt"  , createdAt : "$createdAt" , _distributor : "$_distributor" , status : "$status"} }

   }},
   { $project : {
       _id : "$_id._id",
       data: 1
   }}
])
```

This will give you a document in the following structure, and will add only the filtered records based on `createdAt`

```
{
   _id : "customer 1",
   data : [
      { _id : "" , updatedAt : ""  , createdAt : "" , _distributor : "" , status:""},
      { _id : "" , updatedAt : ""  , createdAt : "" , _distributor : "" , status:""}
   ]
},
{
   _id : "customer 2",
   data : [
      { _id : "" , updatedAt : ""  , createdAt : "" , _distributor : "" , status:""},
      { _id : "" , updatedAt : ""  , createdAt : "" , _distributor : "" , status:""},
     { _id : "" , updatedAt : ""  , createdAt : "" , _distributor : "" , status:""}
   ]
}
```